# Permission for git breaking ssh on git pull

Tags: git, magento, ssh

I'm working on a Magento site which is about to go live, I've [set the permissions of the Magento project as recommended by Magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html) with the below shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to set permissions on Magento as recommeneded in the Magento Docs
# http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \;
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

However after I execute this script I can no longer do a `git pull`, I get a `ssh` error saying it could not resolve the hostname and to check my access rights.

```
$ sudo git pull
ssh: Could not resolve hostname our-git-repo: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The `our-git-repo` is the `host` set in the `~./.ssh/config` file.

I can fix the issue when I change the permissions of the Magento project root to 777 recursively, so I can do a `git pull` successfully.

```
$ sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/magento-project/
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 11, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From our-git-repo:/var/git/magento-project
   175..........376  master     -> origin/master
   fa8..........d24  magento-uat -> origin/magento-uat
Updating 175e490..d6f8376
Fast-forward
 .gitignore | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

**1.** Why should the folder permisions on the Magento project effect **ssh**?

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname our-git-repo: Name or service not known
```

**2.** What permisions should I set in the shell script so that `git pull` work?

## UPDATE

Even after setting the correct permisions on the `.git/` directory I'm still having the same issue.

I think this must be something to do with **ownership**, when I `sudo su` into root and run the `ls -al` command to see the permisons and ownership on `~./.ssh/` I don't see the full contents of the folder.

Any idea why?  Could this be the cause of the issue?

```
$ sudo chmod -R 755 .git/
$ sudo git pull
ssh: Could not resolve hostname our-git-repo: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
$ sudo ls -al ~/.ssh/
total 36
drwx------ 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Aug 28 15:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Sep  3 08:51 ..
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1533 Aug 28 13:35 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  167 Aug 28 15:03 config
-r-------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1671 Aug 28 14:59 dev-aws.pem
-rwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1430 Aug 28 15:00 fz_key.ppk
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3326 Aug 28 14:07 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  759 Aug 28 14:07 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  222 Aug 28 14:02 known_hosts
$ sudo su
# ls -al ~/.ssh/
total 12
drwx------ 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jun 18 16:45 .
drwx------ 4 root   root   4096 Sep  1 13:31 ..
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1097 Aug 28 13:35 authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 3):

The important folder is the `.git` folder in your project. Set write permission for your Git user to that folder. For example:

```
chmod -R 755 .git/
```

Then it should work. You don't need to set the complete folder.

Comment: thanks thats useful info but I'm still having the same issue, could this be an issue with ownership?  I updated my question with some more detail